# CSS in Asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, css

I added a css to a webform. The css worked fine with a html file and also in design view in visual studio. But when it is run in the IIS, the css is not displayed. Please help me out.

**CSS**

```
body{
background: #efefef;
}

.head
{
margin-top:0px;
min-height:40px;
min-width: 102%;
background-color:green;
color:blue;
text-align:center;
margin-left:-10px;
margin-right:0px;
padding-top:10px;

}
#content
{
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-left:0px;
min-height:100%;

}
 #wrapper
  {
  width:83%;
  min-height:inherit;
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
  }
  #sidebar
  {
  width:15%;
  float:right;
  }
  #sidebar1
 {
  background-color:green;
  min-height:20%;
  margin-bottom:2px;
 }
  #sidebar2
  {
  min-height:40%;
  background-color:blue;
margin-bottom:2px;
  }
  #sidebar3
  {
   background-color:violet;
   min-height:40%;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"             Inherits="_Default" %>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="E:\Demo\main.css" />
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">


     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head runat="server">
     <title></title>
    </head>
     <body>
         <form id="form1" runat="server">
             <div class="head">Thiagarajar College of Engineering</div>
         <div id="content">
           <div id="wrapper">
               srini
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar">
            <div id="sidebar1">ji</div>
            <div id="sidebar2">sr</div>
            <div id="sidebar3">ni</div>
            </div>
        </div>
          </form>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: provide more details put some css which are not working. and also put the html for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS file is in wrong place.

1) Typically, CSS file should be inside head tag. (although you can place it in anywhere inside body tag, I do not recommend it).

2) In addition, the link should be relative path instead of `E:\Demo\main.css`

```
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <link href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

paste this code inside the `<head></head>` like this..

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="E:\Demo\main.css" />
</head>
```

If not put your css file inside your project and just drag and drop it in your page..